# Unable to differentiate between Innner and Outer elements in this case

Tags: jquery

From the Ajax response received, I am appending elements to a section as shown below:

```
 success: function (response) {
 var toppingres = response;
 var toppingcart = '<img src="images/arrow-topping.png"/>';
  for (var i = 0; i < toppingres[0].toppings.length; i++){
 toppingcart += '<section class="secclass" id='+id_attr_val+'><i id="topping-close"></i>'
  toppingcart += '<a href="#">'+toppingres[0].toppings[i]+'</a>';
  toppingcart += '</section>';
  }
```

The topping-close shows displays a cross button , so when clicked on that

I have written a Listener for this , so that when clicked on cross  button , i am removing the added elements , but the problem i am facing here 
is that when i selected the a href elements also its removing the section

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass", function () 
{
 var id_attr_val = $(this).attr("id");

 $("section#"+id_attr_val+".secclass").html('');

});
```

[image]

Comment: have you written any click event for that `a` tag..?

Comment: no i have not written for a tag

Comment: Is your a tag class `.secclass`????

Comment: no , but it is present in that section .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicks propagate upward so you need to tell your inner link not to do that.  Off the top of my head that would be something like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Documentation for this here http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Or you could alter your close click event to point directly to the italic close in the section instead of any click on the section

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass i", function () 
{
   $(this).closest(".secclass").html("");
});
```

You might want to actually remove the section instead of just emptying it.  That would be .remove() instead of .html("")

Comment: Since your inner link has a # for the href you must have some code already in place to process clicks of this?  You just need to make sure you pass the event into that function as I show in the example "function (e)" with e being the event.  Then you put e.stopPropagation(); as the first line of code in that function.  This will prevent the click of the secclass section from firing as well.  If you don't stop the propagation it will fire ALL click events starting with the innermost and working outward.

Comment: If i click on closw button its only removing one element of a href , is it possible to remove all the a href elements when clicked on close button ??

Comment: If you mean can you close all your sections of class secclass once the close button is clicked you can.  Just modify your code to $(".secclass").html(""); and it will clear the html out of all of them.   Or .remove() to totally eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your `$(document).ready(){}` function.

```
$("#topping-close").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here `#topping-close` is your `close button ID`.